# how can i implement haskey() function with a query in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I'm translating a program form python to java and I'm working with mysql

at some point I have to check in my db if I have data with a special key.
let's say

```
if(namesTable.haskey(24))
   doSoemthing();
```

I don't need any retrieved data from db I just want to see if there is anything with this special key or not. Additionally, I dont want to use COUNT because using count means to go through all the db and give me a number like 248 while I just care if there is any or not.

I want something to give me a yes as soon as it finds a match in database.

Comment: If your table is properly indexed, then querying for an existing key won't "go through all the db".

Comment: Like `SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE key = value` and check the number of results.

Answer (score 0):

(I interpreted the **"check in my db if I have data with a special key"** to mean that you are checking a single column in a single table for the existence of a particular value. That seems to be the most straightforward interpretation.)

If you need to check a table to see if a row exists in a particular table, with a particular value in a particular column, the most efficient query might be:

```
SELECT 1
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM mytable t
                WHERE t.key = 24
              )
```

The pseudo table DUAL is guaranteed to return no more than one row, and the EXISTS subquery will "exit" with TRUE as soon as one row is found.

For best performance, you'll want an index with key as the leading column, e.g.

```
ON mytable (key)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a flag in your application, like:

```
Boolean hasKey = false;
```

1. On startup of your program, you need to run the sql query against `namesTable` just once to check if it has the special key and on the basis of that query result set the `hasKey`. From then and onwards you don't need to check the db again, and you can simply use:

   if(hasKey)
   {
   soSomething();
   }
2. On add/update of a record in `namesTable`, check if it has special key, if yes then set the `hasKey` flag to `true`.